# Why can't I change the working directory in RStudio?

Tags: r, console, rstudio, working-directory, setwd

I got some example codes from a course that start with

```
install.packages('maps')
install.packages('geosphere')
library(maps)
library(geosphere)
setwd("C:\\mydata")
...
```

Everything was fine until the command of setting working directory. Because I installed RStudio and R in D drive, I have also tried "C://", "C:/", "C:\", "D:\", "D:\", "D://", and "D:/". However, the console kept saying **"Error in setwd( ): cannot change working directory"**.

This is probably a studpid question. But I'm a beginner in R, so could somebody be so kind to help me out? Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried the graphical way from within `RStudio`? Something like `Ctrl + Shift+ H` or `Session - > Set Working Directory -> Choose Directory`?

Comment: Most simple case I can think of is when the directory doesn't exist already.

Comment: Aside from the error, starting R script with `setwd()` is not the best practice: I learned this from [link](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/)

Comment: FYI, using `setwd` in R scripts is a bad coding practice. Use explicit paths as variables.

Comment: Backslashes need to be escaped with backslashes on Windows machines so "C:\\\\mydata" might work *IF* mydata already exists on your machine. Also you can try `setwd(choose.dir())` followed by `getwd()` to get the full path to the directory you selected. But just because the examples used C:\\mydata doesn't mean you have to. Whichever way you go, you can use `dir.create()` to create a new directory/folder for your R work.

Comment: Thank you, everybody! I tried everything you have suggested and some of them seemed to work! ^_^